# Read CSV file from Azure Blob storage in Rstudio Server with spark_read_csv()

Tags: apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr, rstudio-server

I have provisioned an Azure HDInsight cluster type ML Services (R Server), operating system Linux, version ML Services 9.3 on Spark 2.2 with Java 8 HDI 3.6.

Within Rstudio Server I am trying to read in a csv file from my blob storage.

````
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/hdp/current/spark-client")
Sys.setenv(YARN_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf")
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/etc/hadoop/conf")
Sys.setenv(SPARK_CONF_DIR="/etc/spark/conf")

options(rsparkling.sparklingwater.version = "2.2.28")

library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(h2o)
library(rsparkling)


sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client",
                    version = "2.2.0")

origins <-file.path("wasb://MYDefaultContainer@MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net",
                 "user/RevoShare")

df2 <- spark_read_csv(sc,
                 path = origins,
                 name = 'Nov-MD-Dan',
                 memory = FALSE)```
````

When I run this I get the following error

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid method csv 
for object 235
at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:122)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
at 

io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleCh   annelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The path `origins` should point to a CSV file or a directory of CSVs. Are you sure that `origins` points to a directory of files or a file? There's typically at least one more directory under `/user/RevoShare/` for each HDFS user, i.e., `/user/RevoShare/sshuser/`.

Here's an example that may help:

```
sample_file <- file.path("/example/data/", "yellowthings.txt")

library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
cc <- rxSparkConnect(interop = "sparklyr")
sc <- rxGetSparklyrConnection(cc)

fruits <- spark_read_csv(sc, path = sample_file, name = "fruits", header = FALSE)
```

You can use `RxHadoopListFiles("/example/data/")` or use `hdfs dfs -ls /example/data` to inspect your directories on HDFS / Blob.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for helping! I am using the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer and within the RevoShare folder there is a sshuser file but its an application not another folder. 

I have not come across the rxSparkConnect() and rxGetSparklyrConnection() functions. Do you might explaining what they are doing in this context? I read the description on Microsoft's website but it did not make sense to me.

Comment: I'm getting an error that the rxSparkConnect is not cooperating with the rsparkling 


`The environment variable $SPARK_VERSION is not explicitly defined. The system detects a possible version '1.6.3', and attempts to use it to launch Spark application. Please provide $SPARK_VERSION if an alternative version is desired.
Major version of Sparkling Water does not correspond to major Spark version.
                      
Major Sparkling Water Version = 2
Major Spark Version = 1Error in spark_dependencies(spark_version = spark_version, scala_version = scala_version) : `

Comment: Hey @alizaidi would I run the rxSparkConnect(interop = "sparklyr") after setting up the sparklyr connection?

Comment: I think the H20 error is coming from a mismatch in versions installed. Can you first check your version of Spark (1.6.3 seems pretty old, try in bash `spark-submit --version`). The [h2o repo](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/tree/master/r#install-h2o) has instructions on getting the correct version installed for your cluster.

Comment: The `rxSparkConnect` with `interop='sparklyr'` parameter allows you to create a Spark application for `RevoScaleR` but also enable that application to be visible to `sparklyr`, which is connected through `rxGetSparklyrConnection`. This way you can interoperate between `RevoScaleR` and `sparklyr` without having to create multiple applications and migrate data around. Some [tips here in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r/tutorial-sparklyr-revoscaler). HTH!