# How to import/read csv file in R server in azure hdinsight ML service

Tags: r, azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, r-server

Overview:
Azure HDInsight
Cluster Type: ML Services (R Server)
Version: R Server 9.1 (HDI 3.6)

I am trying to import a csv file from Azure data storage blob into R server environment. But it's obviously not as easy as I thought it would be or just as easy as locally.

First thing I tried was installing `sparklyr` package and set connection.

```
#install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")
install.packages("sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn")
```

But due to an old version installed in HDI, there's an error message.

```
Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  : 
  sparklyr does not currently support Spark version: 2.1.1.2.6.2.38
```

Then I tried to use `rxSparkConnect` but didn't work either.

```
#Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME_VERSION="2.1.1.2.6.2.38-1")

cc <- rxSparkConnect(interop = "sparklyr")
sc <- rxGetSparklyrConnection(cc)

orgins <- file.path("wasb://STORAGENAME@CLUSTERNAME.blob.core.windows.net","FILENAME.csv")
spark_read_csv(sc,path = origins, name = "df")
```

How would you read a csv file from azure storage blob into the r server environment?
I'm a little upset at myself that this is taking so long, and it shouldn't be this complicated, please help me guys! Thanks in advance!
[related post 1](https://community.rstudio.com/t/accessing-csv-file-in-azure-blob-storage-via-rstudio-server-with-sparklyr-spark-read-csv/18104)
[related post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275195/read-csv-file-from-azure-blob-storage-in-rstudio-server-with-spark-read-csv)

Answer (score 0):

I found a imperfect work around is to upload the data in the "local" environment in the bottom right corner and simply read the csv file from there.
[image]

There's gotta be a better way to do it, since it's a lot of manual work, probably impractical if data size is big and it's a waste of storage blob.